# Xcode 7: Is keyboard selection from Ctrl + 6, list of file items (methods, etc) possible?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Looking at a swift file, I typed ctrl-6 to see a list of the functions/methods etc in the code file. The list appears at the top of the file, and I could click one of the choices to jump to that location in the file.

But if I start typing, the list is automatically filtered. Eventually I see the one I want to select. But I can't find a keyboard solution to select the item I want.

I've read all the doc, looked in keyboard preferences, searched the net, and have tried all sorts of combinations of cmd, opt, ctrl, shift, and keys such as return, ., <, and even ctrl-p/n to move up and down the list (which keys works in the main editor). But I haven't found anything that works.

Does someone know how to access filtered list from the keyboard?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Down arrow` to access the filtered list.

Comment: I agree that down arrow works. Thank you. I was hoping for other key sequences like tab, return, ctrl p/n, etc that worked with other completions in xcode. But I guess this is all that I get!  Thanks.